# Get the Current Time from Latitude and Longitude Using GeoNames API

Tags: asp.net, api, c#-4.0, geonames

I  am currently creating application which requires Current Time From the Country.
I have latitude and longitude of different Country.

I have use following Link to get the Current Time

http://api.geonames.org/timezone?lat=21.7679&lng=78.8718&username=demo

(demo user name is by default and used only for testing because it has query limit)

I got the current Time but when Daylight Saving Time is ON. Is that API gives me the correct Time? If not then how could i get the current Time.

In some of the API I get the current time like earthtool(not implemented DST). But i could not Test because currently there is no DST Implemented so how can i test in this case?

I am Creating Application in .NET with C# 4.0

If any other API then please Tell Me but first priority to GeoNames API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be *very* surprised if that didn't reflect the current local time. The results for Sao Paolo ([which is currently observing DST](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=233)) seem to agree with that:

```
<geonames>
  <timezone tzversion="tzdata2012f">
  <countryCode>BR</countryCode>
  <countryName>Brazil</countryName>
  <lat>-23.0</lat>
  <lng>-46.0</lng>
  <timezoneId>America/Sao_Paulo</timezoneId>
  <dstOffset>-3.0</dstOffset>
  <gmtOffset>-2.0</gmtOffset>
  <rawOffset>-3.0</rawOffset>
  <time>2012-12-17 10:48</time>
  <sunrise>2012-12-17 06:14</sunrise>
  <sunset>2012-12-17 19:47</sunset>
  </timezone>
</geonames>
```

However, another alternative would be to use the GeoNames API to get the time zone ID, and then use [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) for everything to do with that time zone. (Disclaimer: I'm the primary developer of Noda Time.)

You can't just use the BCL's `TimeZoneInfo` class directly, as that doesn't support TZDB the time zone IDs that GeoNames provides (e.g. "Asia/Kolkata"). You *could* just use a mapping ([CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org) provides one) but in my experience the Windows time zone information has some disturbing oddities.

If you *just* need to know the current time, GeoNames is probably fine -

Comment: Thanks for the Answer.

in <time> tag you get the current time in Brazil. I am talking about this.
Currently there No DST so how can i test that whether DST is implemented in this API?

Comment: Great Answer, I have found that GeoNames has implemented the DST in its API Thanks for the Answer.